# JOOQ wont call DTO setter during custom data type conversion

Tags: java, jooq

I am using the JOOQ library in order to fetch the result from a select query into my custom DTO class. Because my Custom DTO class has an ENUM Type field mapped as an Integer Column in my database I am using a custom data type converter. The query I perform is just a basic select query:

```
public TestSuiteDto findByAuditTestSuiteId(Integer auditTestSuiteId) {

    TestSuiteJTable ts = TestSuiteJTable.TEST_SUITE;
    AuditTestSuiteJTable ats = AuditTestSuiteJTable.AUDIT_TEST_SUITE;

    List<TestSuiteDto> result = dsl.select(
                    ts.ID,
                    ts.DESCRIPTION,
                    ts.PROFILE_TYPE_ID,
                    ts.CREATED,
                    ts.ACTIVE,
                    ts.DEPRECATION,
                    ts.FEEDBACK_QUESTIONNAIRE_ID)
                .from(ts
                    .join(ats).on(ts.ID.eq(ats.TEST_SUITE_ID)))
                .where(ats.ID.eq(auditTestSuiteId))
                .fetchInto(TestSuiteDto.class);
    
    //do some stuff before returning

    return result.get(0); 
}
```

My custom DTO class looks like this

```
@Data
public class TestSuiteDto {

    private Integer id;
    private String description;
    private ProfileType profileType;
    private LocalDateTime created;
    private boolean active;
    private LocalDateTime deprecation;
    private Integer feedbackQuestionnaireId;
}
```

The problem is that during the fetching process the SETTER of the DTO class is never triggered for the ENUM type field e.g. profileType even though I have configured a custom data type converter:

```
@Slf4j
public class ProfileTypeConverter implements Converter<Integer, ProfileType> {

    @Override
    public ProfileType from(Integer databaseObject) {
        log.info("ProfileTypeConverter.from {} -> {}", databaseObject, ProfileType.getFromId(databaseObject));
        return ProfileType.getFromId(databaseObject);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer to(ProfileType userObject) {
        log.info("ProfileTypeConverter.to");
        return userObject.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Integer> fromType() {
        log.info("ProfileTypeConverter.fromType");
        return Integer.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<ProfileType> toType() {
        log.info("ProfileTypeConverter.toType");
        return ProfileType.class;
    }
}
```

I have added some logs just to check if the converter is triggered at all and I see that the converter is triggered as expected (from method of the Converter class is called during the execution of the JOOQ SQL query). I have also delombok my DTO class in order to add logs in SETTERs and GETTERs and see if those are also properly called. I found out that all the SETTERs are properly called except for the profileType one. Because of that when I retrieve the DTO from the result list the value of the profileType field is **null**. The column in my database (mysql) that maps to the profileType ENUM is called PROFILE_TYPE_ID and it is of type Integer. I have also configured a forcedType in the pom.xml following the examples on JOOQ documentation webpage.

```
<forcedType>
   <includeExpression>${jdbc.database}.TEST_SUITE.PROFILE_TYPE_ID</includeExpression>
   <userType>mypackage.type.ProfileType</userType>
   <converter>mypackage.converter.ProfileTypeConverter</converter>
</forcedType>
```

and this is how I have configured the ProfileType Field in pom.xml

```
<field>
    <expression>${jdbc.database}.TEST_SUITE.PROFILE_TYPE_ID</expression>
    <fieldIdentifier>
        <expression>PROFILE_TYPE_ID</expression>
    </fieldIdentifier>
    <fieldMember>
        <expression>profileType</expression>
    </fieldMember>
    <fieldGetter>
        <expression>getProfileType</expression>
    </fieldGetter>
    <fieldSetter>
        <expression>setProfileType</expression>
    </fieldSetter>
</field>
```

JOOQ version: 3.14.16, Java 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why do things behave this way?

The reason is that you have a name mismatch:

**Query**

```java
ts.PROFILE_TYPE_ID,
```

**DTO**

```java
private ProfileType profileType;
```

If you want to rely on the reflection based [`DefaultRecordMapper`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html), then you must name those things accordingly, otherwise, they won't be mapped. The fact that you have a converter is irrelevant, if the names don't match. Imagine you had 20 columns of type `ProfileType`. You wouldn't want to have `DefaultRecordMapper` map values purely based on their type.

#### Regarding your comments:

> I have added some logs just to check if the converter is triggered at all and I see that the converter is triggered as expected (from method of the Converter class is called during the execution of the JOOQ SQL query)

Yes of course. The `Converter` belongs to the projected column. The conversion happens *before* the mapping (i.e. the `into(TestSuiteDto.class)` call)

#### Solutions

There are multiple alternatives to solve this:

- Call your DTO attribute `profileTypeId`, or to add JPA annotations to it to map between SQL names and Java names
- Rename your SQL column (in DDL)
- Alias your SQL column using `PROFILE_TYPE_ID.as("profile_type")`
- Use a computed column `PROFILE_TYPE` and attach the converter to that, keeping the `PROFILE_TYPE_ID` as it is ([you can also use client side computed columns for that](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-computed/), in order not to affect your schema)
- Use type safe constructor based mapping, rather than reflection based mapping, e.g. using `fetch(Records.mapping(TestSuiteDto::new))`

There are probably more possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @Lukas Eder. I see the problem. I tried the first bullet solution and it worked. I have also tried the third bullet solution and it didn't work. I was wondering if the third bullet is equivalent to changing the pom.xml field configuration like this: 

<fieldIdentifier>
    <expression>PROFILE_TYPE</expression>
</fieldIdentifier>. Can you elaborate a little more with the fourth bullet solution, can you give me an example of how to do that?

Comment: `<fieldIdentifier/>` (from a generator strategy) affects only your Java code, not your field name. It has no effect on your mapping behaviour. If you think you've run into a bug regarding the 3rd bullet, please report it here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose. I'll be happy to elaborate on the 4th solution in a new question, where you ask about computed columns. I think it would be a bit of a distraction to future readers of this question, which is mostly about mapping only, not about computed columns.

Comment: I agree with your perspective regarding a new question for computed columns, I will definitely post one when I have some time. But as for the 3rd solution maybe I misunderstood how I should apply the alias PROFILE_TYPE_ID.as("profile_type"). I add it in the dsl.select(ts.PROFILE_TYPE_ID.as("profile_type")).from(table).where(condition). Was that the correct way to do it?

Comment: @KonstantinosRaptis: Yeah, that's what I meant. That alias should work to map into your `TestSuiteDto.profileType` property.